# Conditional Lists of Values in Oracle APEX?

Tags: list, plsql, oracle-apex, lov

I need to use the value of one Select List to populate the value of a second select list, but the items in Select List number two are going to be from a completely different tables depending on what's selected in list number one.

Is there a way I can conditionally populate the second list based on the values from the first?  So far, my attempts to put an if statement into an LOV declaration have been unsuccessful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to use an IF in an Apex LOV is like this:

```
IF :P123_CHOICE = 'EMP' THEN
  RETURN
  'SELECT ename d, empno r
   FROM emp';
ELSE
  RETURN
  'SELECT dname d, deptno r
   FROM dept';
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT ename d, empno r
   FROM emp
   WHERE :P123_CHOICE = 'EMP' 
UNION ALL

SELECT dname d, deptno r
   FROM dept
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is applicable in your case but I have used some `APEX_ITEM` functions in the past to build dynamic objects. You could look into [`APEX_ITEM.select_list_from_query`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#CHDIDGDA) for example to create a select list dynamicaly.